# How to make pattern string in preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

How to make one pattern string for `preg_match_all()` function If I have multiple strings to match like `"G,C,D"` & `"A,B,C"` & `"E,C,D"`

Currently my string is

```
 $str = "/(?<=\b)([CDEFGAB](?:b|bb|m)*(?:#|##|sus|maj|min|aug)*[\d\/]*(?:[CDEFGAB](?:b|bb‌​|m)*(?:#|##|sus|maj|min|aug)*[\d\/]*)*)(?=\s|$|(<.*>))(?! \w)/"

    preg_match_all($str,$lyrics , $output_array);
```

I want to add these combinations `("G,C,D" & "A,B,C" & "E,C,D")` in `$str` string.

Comment: you're example is very simple, but your regular expression is a mile long. can you clarify what you are trying to do? because `preg_match_all( '/(G,C,D|A,B,C|E,C,D)/', $str, $matches )` will provide the solution as stated in your first sentence -- but maybe you are after something more than what is apparent?

Comment: Please add an example string ($lyrics) so that one can reproduce and work on the matching.

Comment: Thanks Jens. How can I add this '/(G,C,D|A,B,C|E,C,D)/' to my existing string.

Comment: @aequalsb How can I add this '/(G,C,D|A,B,C|E,C,D)/' to my existing string.         $str = "/(?<=\b)([CDEFGAB](?:b|bb|m)*(?:#|##|sus|maj|min|aug)*[\d\/]*(?:[CDEFGAB](?:b|bb‌​|m)*(?:#|##|sus|maj|min|aug)*[\d\/]*)*)(?=\s|$|(<.*>))(?! \w)/"

Comment: again, you have not provided enough info to really answer accurately. can you add an example string into your post? and an example string you want to end up with? otherwise, `/(?<=\b)((G,C,D|A,B,C|E,C,D)(?:b|bb|m)*(?:#|##|sus|maj|min|aug)*[\d\/]*(?:(G,C,D|A,B,C|E,C,D)(?:b|bb‌​|m)*(?:#|##|sus|maj|min|aug)*[\d\/]*)*)(?=\s|$|(<.*>))(?! \w)"`, which assumes you want to match literally (WITH the commas) these strings `G,C,D` `A,B,C` `E,C,D`.

Comment: i also noticed at the end of your expression `(<.*>)` -- this will match <.* then ANYTHING until it runs out of charcaters. you need something like this `<[^>]*>` -- which will get it to match any character that is not `>` until it hits a `>`

Comment: @aequalsb   This is my Chords String.

<p>Intro:G,C,D  D, A, Em, G  G,C,D</p>
A,B,C
<p><br />
Verse 1:</p>

<p>    D                   A                  Em <br />
Yeah I've iced down a few thousand beers in my days<br />
  G <br />
You put down twice as many<br />
  D                    A                     Em <br />

Currently my pattern return all chords combination which I need like
C
D
E
F
G
#min
#aug
etc


But now I also need combinations like
"G,C,D" & "A,B,C" & "E,C,D". How can i change my pattern to obtain these results.

Comment: can you put an example string of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: added a new answer -- see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE** this answer has been dramatically edited over time to arrive at this final conclusion.

by referring to this site: http://www.all-guitar-chords.com/ i came up with this regular expression:

`\b(?:G,C,D|A,B,C|E,C,D)|(?:[ABCDEFG](?:#|b)?)(?:\/[ABCDEFG]b)?(?:(?:(?:maj|min|sus|add|aug|dim)(?:\d{0,2}(?:#\d{1,2}|sus\d)?)?)|(?:m\d{0,2}(?:(?:maj|add|#)\d{0,2})?)|(?:-?\d{0,2}(?:\([^)]*\)|#\d{1,2})?))?)`

```
<?php preg_match_all( '`' . $reg_exp . '`', $str, $matches ); ?>
```

my final expression does NOT capture any backreferences. therefore, `$matches[0]` will be an array of the matches (because the zero-index array is always an array of the full strings that matched the full expression and subsequent arrays will refer to backreferences, if any).

it was written with as much precision as possible, but this expression could still return false positives, although very unlikely.

the only other way to do this is to use an array of each of the possible chords you are interested in. then iterate that array searching for each string explicitly -- and that would still be prone to false positives.

here is a site to tinker with it: https://regex101.com/r/vW9sJ2/7

**NOTE** the original question by the OP was how to add certain string combinations into the expression such as "G,C,D" or "A,B,C" (examples given by the OP). however, the musicians i spoke with said they couldn't see how extracting the chord combinations would be helpful as there are so many variations. they weren't even sure how extracting chords like this would help at all. which makes me curious as to what the OP intends to use this for and i hope he can explain for me (especially seeing how much time i spent on this given my obsessesive nature, lol).

**EDIT** without reply from the OP, not sure if this fulfills the OPs needs, and i've begun to wonder if he needs a more flexible match for the combinations (ex: G,C,D). so i've modified the expression to handle that:

`\b(?:[ABCDEFG],[ABCDEFG],[ABCDEFG])\b|(?:[ABCDEFG](?:#|b)?)(?:\/[ABCDEFG]b)?(?:(?:(?:maj|min|sus|add|aug|dim)(?:\d{0,2}(?:#\d{1,2}|sus\d)?)?)|(?:m\d{0,2}(?:(?:maj|add|#)\d{0,2})?)|(?:-?\d{0,2}(?:\([^)]*\)|#\d{1,2})?))?)`

and the fiddle for that: https://regex101.com/r/vW9sJ2/7

Comment: awesome! glad to help. which one did you use? the expression before my edit (at the top)? or the expression after my edit (at the bottom)? and will you mark this as "answered"?

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a way](https://regex101.com/r/wW8qK1/1) to match your *G,C,D*-like strings:

```
\b
(?:(?:[CDEFGAB]
 (?:b|bb|m)*
 (?:\#|\#\#|sus|maj|min|aug)*
 [\d\/]*
 (?:[CDEFGAB]
  (?:b|bb‌​|m)*
  (?:\#|\#\#|sus|maj|min|aug)*
  [\d\/]*
 )*
),?)+
(?=\s|$|(?:<.*>))
(?![[:blank:]]\w)
```

Or as a [one-liner](https://regex101.com/r/wW8qK1/2):

```
\b(?:(?:[CDEFGAB](?:b|bb|m)*(?:\#|\#\#|sus|maj|min|aug)*[\d\/]*(?:[CDEFGAB](?:b|bb‌​|m)*(?:\#|\#\#|sus|maj|min|aug)*[\d\/]*)*),?)+(?=\s|$|(?:<.*>))(?![[:blank:]]\w)
```