# Get only letters in a string INCLUDING whitespace

Tags: php

I have a string with letters and numbers. I want to extract only the letters from the string INCLUDING whitespace.

I tried this:

```
<?php
    $competition = 'New York Nationals - 2016';

    $year = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $competition); 
    $comp = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $competition);
    echo "[$year, $first, 'Comp Name: $comp Date: $year Rank: $first']";
?>
```

The output for `$comp` is `NewYorkNationals`
But what I want it to be is `New York Nationals`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `[^a-zA-Z]` to `[^a-zA-Z\s]`.

```
 <?php
        $competition = 'New York Nationals - 2016';

        $year = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $competition); 
        $comp = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\s]/', '', $competition);
        echo "[$year, $first, 'Comp Name: $comp Date: $year Rank: $first']";
    ?>
```

Comment: You might want to `trim` the result as it will have trailing spaces on it.

Comment: take a look at ArtisticPhoenix's answer below for a much more robust and re-usable solution

Answer (score 1):

use explode

```
$competition = 'New York Nationals - 2016';
$array = explode(' - ', $competition);
$year = $array[1];
$comp = $array[0];
```

**Dealing with variable space around hyphen**

As mentioned in the comments by @aequalsb you can also use `preg_split` For example:

```
$array = preg_split( '/\s*?-\s*?/', $competition );
```

Which will split it even if there are no (or more then one) spaces around `-`.

There is another way to do this to using array map, I like to use array filter with it to.  In this case it's a bit overkill but I will show it anyway.

```
$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode('-', $competition)), function($item){ return strlen($item);});
```

What this does:

Array Map runs a function against all items in the array, in this case `trim` which removes leading and trailing white space. So for example if you split the example string by just `-` you will get something like this:

```
explode('-', $competition);
//output
["New York Nationals "," 2016"]
```

Where they have the extra space.  Array Map and Trim will remove those.

Now array filter will remove any items in an array in which the callback returns false for.  In this case, as I mentioned, it's a bit overkill but an example would be this.

```
 explode('-', "New York Nationals -- 2016");
```

With 2 Hypens, this will output something like this:

```
 ["New York Nationals ",""," 2016"]
```

With an extra array item.  So to remove that we use Array Filter (after the array map) and use a custom callback (because we may want to keep things like 0 in there)

```
  array_filter(["New York Nationals","","2016"], function($item){
       return strlen($item);
  });
```

Strlen, just returns the length of the string, In PHP `0` is also `False` so any items that have a length of `0` will be removed.

As I said it's a but overkill in this case, but it's a very useful thing to know how to do, so I included it just for completeness.

**Dealing with multiple hyphens**

@aequalsb makes another good point in the comments:

> here are lots of answers... and they will all need to be changed as soon as we get something this as an event `Winston-Salem Time Trials - 2016`

For something like this using the answer I posted, you can solve this by using array pop, and implode like this:

```
$competition = 'Winston-Salem Time Trials - 2016';
$array = explode('-', $competition);
//$array = ["Winston","Salem Time Trials ", " 2016"]
$year = trim(array_pop($array));
$comp = trim(implode('-', $array));
```

Array pop, removes and returns the last item in the array. We can be pretty confident that will be the date. So it looks like this:

```
$year = trim(array_pop(["Winston","Salem Time Trials ", " 2016"]));
//result
$year = "2016";
$array = ["Winston","Salem Time Trials "];
```

And then implode is the opposite of explode, which takes $array, puts it back together as a string with the separator (or glue):

```
 $comp = trim(implode('-', ["Winston","Salem Time Trials "]));
 //result
 $comp = "Winston-Salem Time Trials";
```

Which leaves us with what we want:

```
$year = "2016";
$comp = "Winston-Salem Time Trials";
```

We already discuses what Trim does, so I wont go over that again. This last example takes care of both variable spaces around the hyphen, and multiple hyphens.  In this case it's important to trim it after doing implode, we want to preserve any spaces in the original text space (probably).  However, you could use the Array Map and trim first if you don't want any spaces to remain around the hyphens.

An example of that would be this:

```
$competition = 'Winston - Salem Time Trials - 2016'; //note the space "n - S"
$array = array_map('trim', explode('-', $competition));

//$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode('-', $competition)));
//array filter would take care of "Winston -- Salem Time Trials", removing the extra hyphen.

//(without array map, trim) $array = ["Winston "," Salem Time Trials ", " 2016"]
//(with array map, trim) $array = ["Winston","Salem Time Trials", "2016"]
$year = array_pop($array);  //no need to trim
$comp = implode('-', $array);  //no need to trim
//results
$year = "2016";
$comp = "Winston-Salem Time Trials"; //instead of "Winston - Salem Time Trials"
```

I should mention this would take care of any number of hyphens like this.

```
$competition = 'Winston-Salem-Time-Trials - 2016';

//Output
$year = "2016";
$comp = "Winston-Salem-Time-Trials";
```

Hope that makes sense.  As they say "God and the Devil are in the details".  Often the hardest part of any programing is dealing with all the edge cases.

If you want the same thing in Regex

```
preg_match('/(.+?)\s*-\s*(\d+)$/', $str, $match)
```

[Test it online](https://regex101.com/r/pvycQs/2/)

Basically capture everything `?` non-greedy, then the space none or more, hyphen, space none or more, then the digits, and finally an end of line anchor. I just so happen to be pretty good at Regex too.  I just didn't want to step on anyone's toes as the other answers focused on it.

Enjoy!

Comment: this is the best answer if you can rely on ` - ` being consistent between entries. otherwise you can use `preg_split( '/\s*?-\s*?/', $competition );` in place of `explode`

Comment: Or you can do `array_map('trim', explode('-', $competition))`  I like doing it this way though `array_filter(array_map('trim', explode('-', $competition)), function($item){ return strlen($item);});`  Which will not only remove leading and trailing space, but also any empty (strlen 0) array items.

Comment: there are lots of answers... and they will all need to be changed as soon as we get something this as an event `Winston-Salem Time Trials - 2016`

Comment: @aequalsb - thanks I needed a break from moving all these wordpress sites, I get bored waiting on the DNS updates .... lol ... I have to move around 10 WP sites from one hosting account to another, in the same godaddy account.  I have a client that is upgrading from basic hosting to C-Panel.  I also have to manually move them for a few reasons I won't mention on here.  But DNS frustrates me sometimes.

Comment: Its not hard to solve multiple `-` in regex.  `preg_match('/(.+?)\s*-\s*(\d+)$/', $str, $match)` for [Example](https://regex101.com/r/pvycQs/2).  Non-greedy with an end of line anchor.

Comment: i'm very familiar with regular expressions (including deep opnes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287776/how-to-make-pattern-string-in-preg-match-all/30313494#30313494 for example) -- but i like when things can be resolved without them because it is often more readable and logical when reading the code for others (and myself coming back to it after a long period of time)

Comment: I thought about using `strrchr`  as in `strrchr($competition, '-')` then with some judicial use of trim and str_replace.  Or `strrpos` and `substr`  But I didn't feel like explaining those as they are `underused` by most ppl

Comment: the real question here is: how is the OP getting data?. the BEST scenario would be that a query of some kind to a database or API returns the data as an array already. the OP's question (with only one example) suggests they are getting the data from some source formatted into a string already (at least i can't imagine someone storing data in a string like that). if this is the only way they can receive the data, then these solutions will apply -- but i challenge the OP to consider digging deeper into how to get the "data as data".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

    $str = "This is sample string containing number 172, special chars )(*&^%$#@!':;[]{}><?";

    preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z\s]+/', $str, $matches);

    print_r($matches);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => This is sample string containing number 
            [1] =>  special chars 
        )

)
```

Online Demo: [enter link description here](https://3v4l.org/WuX03)

Answer (score 0):

If your original string has a predictable format, you can also use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get your parts instead of substituting:

```
$competition = 'New York Nationals-2016';

// Define two capturing groups, first alphanumeric characters.
// Optional whitespaces and dash separator.
// Second composed of four digits.
// U modifier: Ungreedy match. Try to match as little characters as possible 
//   so trailing whitespace is not captured.
$expr = '/^([a-zA-Z\s]+)\s*-?\s*([0-9]{4})$/U';

// Check that we got all parts we are interested in
if (preg_match($expr, $competition, $matches)) {
    $comp = $matches[1];
    $year = $matches[2];
    echo "Comp Name: $comp Date: $year";
}
```